# How to turn strings in a sequence into a float?

Tags: python, sequence

I am new to Python and I cant figure this out. Here is my code:

```
salesFile = input("Enter sales file name: ")
totalFiles = input("Enter name for total sales file: ")

salesFileOpen = open(salesFile, "r")
sales = salesFileOpen.readlines()

for line in sales:
    newLine = (line.strip().split(" "))

for number in newLine:
    totals = float(newLine[number]) + float(newLine[number])
print(newLine)
print(totals)
```

The file I enter as salesFile, comes out as

```
['$1120.47', '$944.42']
['$72.29', '$588.23']
['$371.21', '$2183.84']
```

I need to add each value in the horizontal rows and have a total for each row.  To do that, I tried doing

```
totals = float(newLine[number]) + float(newLine[number])
```

It returns as an error saying this:

```
totals = float(newLine[number]) + float(newLine[number])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `float(newLine[number][1:])` or split list by `,`

Comment: If you Google the phrase "Python list total" and "Python convert money to float", you’ll find tutorials that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.

Comment: Also, please note that your addition statement adds a number to itself.  You might also work through an example on running sums.

Answer (score 0):

You're seeing an error because iterating over a list of strings so number is actually a string, and indexing by a string doesn't make sense. Theres no need to index.

Replace

```
for number in newLine:
    totals = float(newLine[number]) + float(newLine[number])
```

with:

```
for number in newLine:
    totals = float(number[1:]) + float(number[1:])
```

Wrapping things together:

```
for i, line in enumerate(sales):
    newLine = (line.strip().split(" "))

    total = 0
    for number in newLine:
        total += float(number[1:]) 

    print 'Total for line # {} is: {}'.format(i + 1,  total)
```

Comment: Dont you think it will double the number. `x+x =2x`

Comment: Sure, was only responding to the issue about the error. But updated to provide an overall solution for printing sum on each line also